# Lightning Usage/Adoption Reports and Metrics (e.g. most viewed pages, switches to Classic, etc.)

Tags: lightning-experience, reporting, metadata, tooling-api, usagemetrics

Salesforce's native "Lightning Usage App" app (Summer '18) includes several reports with metrics around page views, load times, mobile activity, etc.

I find the "Most Viewed Pages" usage report below interesting, and would like to build some customization around this data.  Does anyone know **which metadata type this data is based off, and if it's accessible to us clients?**

[image]

I'm familiar with the *VisualforceAccessMetrics* object, but this report seems to encompass ALL screens that a user might view, not just VF pages.

Comment: Some of this data seems related to the user actions tracked by Event Monitoring (Salesforce Shield), but not sure if it's related

Answer (score 0):

The following objects store Lightning metrics & usage and are available for custom Reports (via a custom Report Type) as well as SOQL queries:

- [LightningExitByPageMetrics](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_lightningexitbypagemetrics.htm)
- [LightningToggleMetrics](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_lightningtogglemetrics.htm)
- [LightningUsageByAppTypeMetrics](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_lightningusagebyapptypemetrics.htm)
- [LightningUsageByBrowserMetrics](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_lightningusagebybrowsermetrics.htm)
- [LightningUsageByFlexiPageMetrics](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_lightningusagebyflexipagemetrics.htm)
- **[LightningUsageByPageMetrics](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_lightningusagebypagemetrics.htm)**